# Python urllib simple login script

Tags: python, authentication, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to make a script to login into my "check card balance" service for my university using python. Basically it's a web form where we fill-in our PIN and PASS and it shows us how much $$$ is left on our card (for food)...

This is the webpage: [url]http://www.wcu.edu/11407.asp[/url]

This is the form I am filling:

```
<FORM method=post action=https://itapp.wcu.edu/BanAuthRedirector/Default.aspx><INPUT value=https://cf.wcu.edu/busafrs/catcard/idsearch.cfm type=hidden name=wcuirs_uri> 
<P><B>WCU ID Number<BR></B><INPUT maxLength=12 size=12 type=password name=id> </P>
<P><B>PIN<BR></B><INPUT maxLength=20 type=password name=PIN> </P>
<P></P>
<P><INPUT value="Request Access" type=submit name=submit> </P>
</FORM>
```

As you will see the fields i need to fill in are:

```
<input maxlength="12" size="12" type="password" name="id">
<input maxlength="20" type="password" name="PIN">
```

then I need to press the button:

```
<input value="Request Access" type="submit" name="submit">
```

When i do this in my browser, this takes me to another page where it shows my balance and id in simple html...

So I tried to write a python script that would give the the html of that page (so I could parse out the amount of money I have left and print it to the screen)

This is what I have so far:

```
import urllib                                                                   
import urllib2                                                                  
import sys                                                                      
import cookielib                                                                
import hashlib                                                                  

cookieJar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()                                            
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))           

opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', "Mozilla/5.0")]                             

username = "xxxxxxx"                                                          
password = "xxxxxxxx"                                                             
action   = "https://itapp.wcu.edu/BanAuthRedirector/Default.aspx"        

print hashlib.md5(hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest()).hexdigest()                
#url = "http://www.wcu.edu/11407.asp"                                           
url = "http://www.wcu.edu/11407.asp"                                            
form = {"action" : action,                                                      
        "id" : username,                                                        
        "PIN" : password}                                                       

encodedForm = urllib.urlencode(form)                                            
request = urllib2.Request(url, encodedForm)                                     
page = opener.open(request)                                                     
contents = page.read()                                                          

f = open("mycatpage.txt", "w")                                                  
f.write(contents)                                                               
f.close()
```

Why does't this work???

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I made a new version of the script, but it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkbalance3.py", line 20, in <module>
    open("mycatpage.html", 'w').write(opener.open(request))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 513, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 438, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 521, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

This is the code:

```
from urllib import urlopen, urlencode                                           
import urllib2                                                                  

myId = 'xxxxxxxx'                                                              
myPin = 'xxxxxxx'                                                                

data = {                                                                        
            'id':myId,                                                          
            'PIN':myPin,                                                        
            'submit':'Request Access',                                          
            'wcuirs_uri':'https://cf.wcu.edu/busafrs/catcard/idsearch.cfm'      
        }                                                                       

opener = urllib2.build_opener()                                                 
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]                              

url = 'https://itapp.wcu.edu/BanAuthRedirector/Default.aspx'                    
request = urllib2.Request(url, urlencode(data))                                 

open("mycatpage.html", 'w').write(opener.open(request))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: use firebug and see that post parameters are: PIN,id,submit(value :Request Access), wcuirs_uri(value:https://cf.wcu.edu/busafrs/catcard/idsearch.cfm); so try changing your `form` values

Comment: `Error 500: Internal Server Error` tells you that the server caused an exception. So, server knows about the error and imo you can't do much about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this (seems working, at least no exception):

```
from urllib import urlopen, urlencode
myId = '<your_id_here>'
myPin = '<your_pin_here>'
data = {
            'id':myId,
            'PIN':myPin,
            'submit':'Request Access',
            'wcuirs_uri':'https://cf.wcu.edu/busafrs/catcard/idsearch.cfm'
        }

url = 'https://itapp.wcu.edu/BanAuthRedirector/Default.aspx'
response = urlopen(url, urlencode(data))
open("mycatpage.txt",'w').write(response.read())
```

Comment: The page I get back is still the login page...
It's the same page I started with...

Any ideas?

Comment: I gave the wrong url (copied from your url, :p)... changed it; note that the form is submitted to the url written in the `action` attribute

Comment: but we never specify the action attribute url....
This one: https://itapp.wcu.edu/BanAuthRedirector/Default.aspx

Comment: It should not show login page; note that `url` is different than the login page (https://itapp.wcu.edu/BanAuthRedirector/Default.aspx); I am getting runtime-exception page (from browser) all time, so I cant verify

Comment: copied and pasted exactly what you have... (even checked the user and pass in browser first) Same result...

How does it know to enter that information in the login page (http://www.wcu.edu/11407.asp) if we never specify it? I am just not sure exactly how this works (never did any web dev)

Comment: browser shows you the login page so that it can get information from you. After that, browser sends those information to the `action` url. In this case, we already have information, so we don't need to visit/call the login page

Comment: ok, got it.... turns out I had the wrong url... (thought I corrected it with sed..... I didnt....)

Well now I get a difrrent page, but not what I want... 
The top says "Server Error in '/BanAuthRedirector' Application."

Comment: Thats the error from your server (exactly which I am receiving from my browser)

Comment: Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine
Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tagshould then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off"

Comment: Any idea why? perhaps the flash embedded in the page checks to see that I am running a real browser?

If so, how would I make it think I am... ?

Comment: I saw that from my browser; cant say about that as error details are not allowed to be spitted from the server. Cant help without error details, sorry

Comment: hum.... Any idea what's something I could do?
How would I set my headers to mimic a browser that is sending those requests?

Comment: thanks for your reply, at least now I know how the whole process works... If you think of a way to not get the error messg, please reply, thx