# multiple instances of python in separated windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation, ui-automation, python-2.x

I'm using [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput) and I want to run multiple python scripts in separate windows
is it possible to make the script run inside of a window while still allowing me to do other things with my mouse and keyboard simultaneously?
I'm using the latest version of ubuntu and python 2.7.3

how can I attach python code to a window?

Comment: You can't just pop open another terminal window?...

Comment: PyUserInput takes control of my mouse and keyboard, I'm using it to automate tasks in a specific window but also want to be able to use them to do other things at the same time

Comment: Why not use scripts for handling those tasks instead?  What would require manipulating your mouse and keyboard, a game?

Comment: can you press a button and enter characters into a textbox with scripts?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for access to a website, normally yes.  Some sites disable the ability to enter data into text fields, such as with a login, so be careful about that. I would do some research on Python's urllib2 module.

Here's a good example: [Python urllib simple login script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037992/python-urllib-simple-login-script)

Also, when it comes to working with scripts to handle these processes, it isn't typically about "pushing buttons", that's for when dealing with GUI's.  Rather than working with GUI's themselves, you want to work with the underlying processes they serve.

Comment: how can I find out what "the underlying processes they serve" are?

Comment: [Well](http://www.troll.me/images/futurama-fry/cant-tell-if-trolling-or-serious-thumb.jpg), you could try googling urllib examples related to what you're trying to do, whatever that may be.